# I need to prove a formula but I'm not sure how

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a problem with the goal of finding a general formula and proof for the number of ways to arrange a string of 2n bits so that the number of 1's is strictly greater than the number of 0's I've figured out how to do it, but I don't know how to prove it.

Here's what I have so far.

To calculate it for a given number, in this case let's say 5, 2*5 = 10 so I need to do 10c6 + 10c7 +...+ 10c10 = 386

I've broken that down to (2^2n - 2n c(comb) n) / 2

For the case above that'd be (2^2(5) - 2(5) c(comb) n) /2 = (1024 - 252) / 2 = 386

Once again, my problem is I don't know how to prove it. I figure it's probably by induction, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: There are $2^{2n}$ bit strings with $2n$ bits. $\binom{2n}n$ have $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones. Half of the rest have more ones than zeroes, and the other half have more zeroes than ones. The number with more ones than zeroes is therefore ... ?

Comment: I already figured out how to calculate it. My problem is proving it. If you look above, I have the formula written.

Comment: @James: And my hint shows you how to prove it. That, not the formula, was the point of the hint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I know why it's the correct formula. It's because each number aside from 2nCn is the combinations where the 1's and 0's are equal and there are the same number of combinations where there are fewer 1's and as there are where there are more 1's so I divide it by 2. But I don't know how to show that mathematically

Comment: @James: You’re trying to make it harder than it really is. What I wrote **is** a proof once the last sentence is completed with $$\frac12\left(2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n\right)=2^{2n-1}-\frac12\binom{2n}n=2^{2n-1}- \binom{2n-1}n$$ or the like.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much

Comment: @James: You’re welcome.